# Android device with two wifi adapter

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have a custom hardware with Two separate WiFi adapter. Android M will be the OS running on it. 
What i am trying to achieve is use one adapter as dedicated and other for normal use like tethering, internet, etc.

How can i achieve this?

I am thinking like making changes in android-OS level. How can i do that?

In current case we can enable or disable wifi as follows

```
WifiManager mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

How to do that for a device with two wifi modules.